# Webpack проблема с областью видимости

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6

Добрый день! Есть несколько модулей, которые подключены к app.js, вот например код, который лежит внутри:

```
var test = "TEST";
```

Вот мой webpack.config

```
module.exports = {
    entry: './src/app.js',
    output: {
        filename: './dist/bundle.js'
    }
};
```

Проблема заключается в том, что когда я пытаюсь вызвать мою переменную test в консоли разработчика, то получаю ошибку: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что-то с областью видимости, когда я подключаю app.js напрямую - все работает, в чем проблема и как исправить?
Заранее большое спасибо!

Comment: А покажите app.js полностью? Если у вас дальше не используется test, то webpack вполне мог её удалить.

Answer (score 1):

У тебя test лежит в сборке не в той области видимости. Это исправить можно несколькими способами:

1.

app.js:

```
var test = "TEST"
Object.assign(window, {
  test: test
  // Этот шаблон можно использовать для того, чтобы расширить область видимости нескольких переменных, ..., хотя можно и просто написать window.test = test
})
```

2.

app.js:

```
var test = "TEST"

module.exports = {test: test}
```

wepback.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
    entry: './src/app.js',
    output: {
        filename: './dist/bundle.js',
        library: 'global' // libarary - параметр, который принимет имя перименной (глобальной), в которую будет помещено то, что будет экспортировано с точки входа (в даном примере - ./src/app.js)
    }
};
```

Тогда к `test` можно с помощью периеменой `global`: `global.test`

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Добавил в webpack.config global, но теперь global.test выдает undefined. Подскажи пожалуйста, как при работе с вебпаком правильно настраивать область видимости, есть ли какой- то стандарт, что бы таких проблем не было? Спасибо!